# What could be the reason for php-pear being so slow on my local Ubuntu VM?

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, virtualbox, pear

I got an Ubuntu Raring Ringtail (Beta) VirtualBox VM running and connect to it via SSH. When using "pear install" and try to install "phing/phing" from "http://pear.phing.info/" it takes *ages* for the command to even find the mentioned package. The download speed is normal, but searching/finding the package takes so long.

I've used php-pear not too many times until now, so maybe I'm doing something wrong. Also commands like "pear upgrade-all" is so slow and didn't fix my problem after running it.

Any idea what could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 1):

You are probably having DNS problems. Check your DNS setup in that VM - if you have two DNS servers setup, and the first does not respond, it will take some time until the DNS libs notice that and switch to the second DNS server.

You can also use Wireshark on your host to find out which network requests are being sent and which fail.